# Titanium iPhone store variable value in shared preference

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am new on titanium and iPhone development, i want to know how to store value of variable in share preference and get that value on another js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple example demonstrating use of `Titanium App Properties module`

I am setting a Boolean value for `service_running` in service.js and validating in app.js

**app.js**

```
var isRunning = Ti.App.Properties.getBool("service_running", false);

if (isRunning) 
    Ti.API.info('service is running');
else 
    Ti.API.info('service is not running');
```

In **service.js**

```
Ti.App.Properties.setBool("service_running", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

The App Properties module is used for storing application-related data in property/value pairs that persist beyond application sessions and device power cycles.

Examples

```
Store a property
Store a string property.

Ti.App.Properties.setString('givenName', 'Paul');
Ti.API.info('The value of the givenName property is: ' + Ti.App.Properties.getString('givenName'));
```

[More.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties)